# Pro Tools 10 bouncing regions/cips with fades?

Tags: pro-tools, export

I was wondering what methods people are using in pro tools 10 to export individual regions/clips as individual sounds while retaining any fades or processing or even clip gain?  Seems like whenever I export the clips I only get the raw recorded file which isn't particularly useful to me when trying to get hundreds of sounds that have all been treated and have fades in place. What is the best method(s) to do this?  I'm at a loss... Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an internal bounce (route through a bus and record to another audio track). That would lock in all the processing, fades, etc. without the hassle of dealing with the Bounce to Disk window. You can even create interleaved or mono files as necessary by making that change in the Session Setup window.

Comment: Yup. This pretty much guarantees it. I like the idea of choosing to create interleaved files before re-recording too. Although I do like to CMD+Shift+K export.

Answer (score 1):

Hey,
You can bounce the individual regions ('clips' in PT 10) by soloing the track, selecting the region and then opt+cmnd+B. When the bounce window pops, in the bounce source, select the proper output. (Output--->Built-in Output)
I think that should help you out and all your fades and plugin settings will get printed as well. I hope that's what you meant.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

consolidate the clip and it renders the fade and gain. shift+option+3

Comment: Consolidate won't give the desired result if any plug-in processing is on the track.

Comment: correct, but i don't see a mention of plug ins hanging on channels. he mentions exporting the clips which seems to suggest that he is either processing the clips (audiosuite) prior to, or does not have plug-in processing.  if he does, then a simple busing and printing from one track to the next will print out all processing.  pretty standard practice.

Comment: even if he does have plugin processing on the channel he can copy/paste the plugin setting to the same plug in in audiosuite and render it out. change the setting from "create continuous file" to "create individual" and process multiple clips at once. then export.

Comment: He's exporting clips and all he's getting is the "raw audio" with no processing or clip gain. That says to me that he's using plug-ins. Perhaps even getting fancy and automating them. Copy/paste from TDM/RTAS to AS is great if everything on the channel remains constant. Make one automation move and you're boned.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to "batch export" your regions/clips so you don't have to export them one by one? Do you have plugins with automation on the tracks? Or are there just plugins without automation?

I guess Shaun's suggestion will be the safest, because you can also listen and stop if there's somerhing not sounding right. Then pick up recording again. If you need to create individual files you could use strip silence, but that of course depends on your audio content. If there are silences in your files that need te stay there you could use Quickeys to automate a process of selecting the original regions and then using the selection to create the new clips from your recording/bounce. I hope this doesn't sound too unclear... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone, sounds like bussing or consolidation is the way to go.  I've been mainly concerned about getting the fades, but I was hoping to use a limiter on the tracks as well, sounds like this isn't going to work unless I commit the processing?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If all you've done is used clip gain and added some fades, consolidating will be the faster way to go.

Duplicate your playlist so you can backtrack if necessary. Highlight everything, right click on a region and go to Clip Gain > Render Clip Gain. This will write new files based on the clip gain levels and retain all of your edits. After you render the clip gain, then consolidate your regions and export them. If you really want to use a limiter you can apply it as an AS to your consolidated regions, render, and then export.

But, if you've added any automation; volume, pan, plug-in, *anything*, I recommend Shaun's internal bounce over a bounce to disk. If for no other reason than you can interrupt and continue an internal re-record when you hear an error, and can't when bouncing to disk.

Comment: And if I may add to that, remember that consolidated clips are named after the track they're on. So for instance trackname 'SFX 1' will be the first part of all your clips with an incremental number added to that. I hate that by the way, why can't it just keep the original name and add a number? 

Comment: Excellent point @Arnoud, same as if you're re-recording to a new track. So save yourself some leg-work and rename the track you're either working on, or recording to. Otherwise there's a handy little applescript that can "add to file names" or "trim file names"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve, will definitely try this approach.